# Draw a circle on gisMap

Tags: javascript, d3.js, gis, esri, arcgis-js-api

I dont know how can i draw a circle on gismap.

After click on button function get a radius for circle (val).
If radius is == 1 then i want to draw circle on radius 1 on the map using this cord as a center of circle (21.1, 52.14).

How do this using d3.js?

Code:

```
function map()
{
      var map;

      require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",  //For full list of pre-defined basemaps, navigate to http://arcg.is/1JVo6Wd
          center: [14.70, 52.53], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 6
        });
      });

}

    function DrawCircle()
    {
        var val = document.getElementById("InputMin1").value;

   if(val == 1)
    {
        var svg = d3.select('svg');
        var originX = 21.1; 
        var originY = 52.14;
        var outerCircleRadius = 100;

        var outerCircle = svg.append("circle").attr({
            cx: originX,
            cy: originY,
            r: outerCircleRadius,
            fill: "none",
            stroke: "black"
        });
    }
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, As I am understanding you just want to add a circle of certain distance  on the esri map.

Below running sample draw a circle on a center **(21.1, 52.14)**.

```js
var map;

      require(["esri/map", "esri/geometry/Circle", "esri/layers/GraphicsLayer","esri/graphic", "esri/units", "esri/geometry/Point", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", "esri/symbols/SimpleLineSymbol", "esri/Color"], function(Map, Circle,GraphicsLayer, Graphic, Units, Point,SimpleFillSymbol, SimpleLineSymbol, Color) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "topo",  
          center: [14.70, 52.53], // longitude, latitude
          zoom: 5
        });
        
       var centerPoint = new Point([21.1, 52.14]);
  var circleGeometry = new Circle({
    center: centerPoint,
    radius: 100,             // add distance
    radiusUnit: Units.MILES, // add distance unit
    geodesic: true
  });
        var gl = new GraphicsLayer({ id: "circles" });
        map.addLayer(gl);
         var sfs = new SimpleFillSymbol(SimpleFillSymbol.STYLE_SOLID,
    new SimpleLineSymbol(SimpleLineSymbol.STYLE_DASHDOT,
    new Color([255,0,0]), 2),new Color([255,255,0,0.25])
  );
        var graphic = new Graphic(circleGeometry,sfs);
        gl.add(graphic);
      });
```

```css
html, body, #map {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/esri/css/esri.css">
 <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.16/"></script>

     

   <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>
```

***Hoping this will help you :)***

Answer (score 1):

I know this doesn't answer the question regarding D3.js but if there is no specific reason to use D3, why not use the `esri/geometry/Circle` module? It's already included in the Esri JS API so you don't have to pull in an extra library.

> A circle (Polygon) created by a specified center point. This point can be provided as an esri/geometry/Point object or an array of latitude/longitude values.

Reference: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/circle-amd.html

Example: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/graphics_create_circles.html

Comment: The reason is the main coder using d3.js on math module. So i must do this via this lib

Comment: Ok, understood. I'll leave the answer as-is, might come in handy for other people wanting to draw circles with Esri without D3